# TabPageIndicator not style properly inside Fragment

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, viewpagerindicator

I'm trying to put `com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator` in the `SherlockFragment`. While the scrolling of content in `ViewPager` works very well, the styling of TabPageIndicator is not working properly. This pager hold five fragments and their titles would not fit the width of the screen. I have this working fine in Activity but when I try using this in Fragment, all five titles got cut off to fit the width of the screen.

I tried using both `LayoutInflater` provided in `Fragment#onCreateView` and `getSystemService` both result in the same result.

Not sure if related but I also have com.actionbarsherlock.widget.SearchView in this layout and all the attributes weren't applied.

**my_search_layout.xml**

```
    <com.viewpagerindicator.TabPageIndicator
            android:id="@+id/indicator"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            />
    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_below="@id/indicator"
            />
</RelativeLayout>
```

**MySearchFragment**

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        LayoutInflater themedInflater = (LayoutInflater) getSherlockActivity()
                                                            .getSupportActionBar()
                                                            .getThemedContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

        View root = themedInflater.inflate(R.layout.my_search_layout, container, false);

        FragmentManager fm = ((Fragment)this).getChildFragmentManager();

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(fm);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) root.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabPageIndicator indicator = (TabPageIndicator) root.findViewById(R.id.indicator);
        indicator.setViewPager(mViewPager);

        return root;
    }
```

**SectionsPagerAdapter**

```
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int i) {
            Fragment fragment = null;

            Log.d(TAG, "SectionsPagerAdapter: " + i);

            fragment = new HelloFragment();

            return fragment;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return 5;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return getString(R.string.section_title_page_1);
                case 1:
                    return getString(R.string.section_title_page_2);
                case 2:
                    return getString(R.string.section_title_page_3);
                case 3:
                    return getString(R.string.section_title_page_4);
                case 4:
                    return getString(R.string.section_title_page_5);
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Comment: No, the design was changed to something completely different so I stop working on this.